# Bluetooth connection in foreground service

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, foreground-service

I am developing an Android app for connecting to a Bluetooth device with callbacks for button presses. I want to add a foreground service that implements Bluetooth connectivity and gatt connection as well as having the bottom presses.

And all this should happen even if the app is killed or closed.

Edit:
The question was a bit vague and not showing my efforts to solve it on my own. But as of 2 years now, it was already completed and accepted an answer from below

Comment: Welcome to SO...Please do some search on it before posting the question here. We are all here to help but first, you need to do some effort on it. Please refer this before posting question here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have been working on this for over a month. Created a separate library to connect to the custom built PCB and having the BluetoothLE connectivity in normal app life cycle. But services are new to me and after reading plenty of material on separate topics for services notification and Bluetooth, i felt the need to ask for answers here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First do check the scenario for foreground services. Is this what you actually need? [consider this blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/12/effective-foreground-services-on-android_11.html)
- [Here's](https://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/) an example of foreground service that you might want to see.
- And this [bluetooth overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth) would help too.